# Convert a String into python list that is already in list format

Tags: python, json, list, unicode

i have users emails  stored in database like this below.

```
['abc@gmai.com','abc@gmail.com','abc@gmail.com']
```

I have to get each email of all users one by one. After querying i wrote the following code.

```
    cur.execute("sql query")
                rows = cur.fetchall()
                for row in rows:
                    print row[2]
                    print type(row[2])
                    emails = json.loads(json.dumps(row[2]))
                    print type(emails)

<type 'str'>
<type 'unicode'>
```

it converts it into Unicode instead of list.

Comment: The SQL Query returns a list? What is the expected output?

Comment: the sql query returns a list of records, i also checked it by `print row[2]` and it prints all the list of emails as i show above. you can see in code that it says it is string.

Comment: @MTaqi: what does `repr(row[2])` produce?

Comment: In any case, `json.dumps()` then `json.loads()` is not going to work, even if the row contained some kind of JSON data.

Comment: @MartijnPieters why? explain?

Comment: @MTaqi; because it isn't clear to me what exactly is contained in `row[2]`. `print repr(row[2])` would give us the information we need to help you properly.

Comment: @MTaqi: using `json.dumps(something)` produces a JSON *encoding* of `something`, which you then decode again with `json.loads()`. You just encoded to JSON and that encoding was then decoded again. The only thing that achieves is that you test if a string can be JSON encoded (it can) and the result is a Unicode string with the same contents as what you started with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `row[2]` is a string. To convert it to a list you could use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html):

```
In [29]: text = "['abc@gmai.com','abc@gmail.com','abc@gmail.com']"

In [30]: import ast

In [31]: ast.literal_eval(text)
Out[31]: ['abc@gmai.com', 'abc@gmail.com', 'abc@gmail.com']

In [32]: type(ast.literal_eval(text))
Out[32]: list
```

Comment: There is no list being built. The OP is converting each email address to JSON and back.

Comment: He shows `print row[2]` prints `['abc@gmai.com','abc@gmail.com','abc@gmail.com']`. Notice there are three print statements, and three lines of output.

Comment: I am not convinced that that's the case. Also, some databases allow for JSON results in a column that is then decoded when querying. See http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#json-adaptation for example.

Comment: And the `print` statements *in the code* don't match up with the output produced *below* the code. The list at the top of the answer is not necessarily one such `row[2]` being printed.